# What is the word for "inclined to vote in an election"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for something analogous to how "litigious" means "unreasonably prone to go to law to settle disputes". Is there a word for this?

The best I can come up with is "democratically inclined" or something equally complicated.

Edit: Here is a hypothetical usage--

"I voted today. I'm so _______!"

analogous to

"I just sued someone today. I'm so litigious."

Comment: Good citizen ?.

Comment: I was also considering "patriotic" (which is similar to what you've said) but that also seems to have a much broader meaning

Comment: [Puff Daddy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9pSh0VAVYn4)?

Comment: I don't think there's such a word. If there were, I'm pretty sure we'd have heard it on the news many times in the past few weeks.

Comment: How about something involving the word "suffrage", such as "suffragistic"? I guess that's not a word ...

Comment: Seems like "slanted" would fit.

Comment: (Actually, "enfranchised" comes close.)

Comment: If you're interested in coining such a term, I suggest _ballotropic_.

Comment: I'm not a native, but why not _the likely electorate_?

Comment: @Itsme, I'm looking for a word to describe a single person. For example "I voted today. I'm so _______!" where the blank would be filled in with the word I'm talking about. Things like "democratically inclined" could work there but I thought there might already be a word

Comment: @Sven, I don't get it.

Comment: It's just _ballot_ plus _-tropic_ ("turning toward or having an affinity for"), with the consonant doubling dropped.

Comment: In Ireland they used to have an expression: *Vote early, vote often*. I don't know if that has anything to do with what you are asking?

Comment: Can you write your hypothetical usage of the requested term from your comment into your question post?

Comment: Another neologistic term would be *suffrageous*.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you want an adjective that describes your virtue, rather than just the act of voting (which would be redundant anyway in your example sentence).

[**Civic-minded**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/civic-minded)

> *adjective*
>   1. concerned with the well-being of the community.

Comment: Dang! I think that might be even more appropriate than my *politically engaged*. Neither of them specifically evoke "willingness to vote" to the exclusion of other activities concerned with how a community establishes/upholds its values, but I think we can take it for granted both *politically engaged* and *civic-minded* individuals almost certainly *would* vote (and actively try to persuade others to do likewise).

Answer (score 2):

The phrase that's usually used in news reporting about upcoming elections is *likely voters*.

But if you're looking for an adjective, rather than a name for the people, I suspect there isn't one. It seems like it would be used often in news discussions of election predictions and voter apathy, yet I've never heard it.

Comment: Thank you but I'm looking for an adjective, not a noun, analogous to my example: "litigious".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a single-word term (or at least, I can't call one to mind), but ***politically engaged*** seems like a reasonable adjectival phrase to identify people who care enough to vote in pursuit of their political ideals.

That's as opposed to *politically **active***, which I would generally understand to mean people who *stand* for election (or actively canvass in support of their preferred candidate).

---

OP's *litigious* is invariably a pejorative usage for someone who takes advantage of the legal system to promote their own self-interest. But ***democratic*** is usually a desirable attribute, and it doesn't denote someone who takes advantage of a voting system for personal gain.

Answer (score 0):

Politicians are often said to have "mobilized" certain demographics, meaning they've motivated certain groups to vote. Those (potential) voters could be called "mobilized," though without the right context the meaning would not be clear, so it's not a perfect analogue to the unambiguous "litigious."

Answer (score 0):

You can consider ***election-minded***.

There is no dictionary entry for this neologism but it has a prevalent usage. There are a lot of results when you search on [Google](https://www.google.ca/search?safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22election-minded%22&btnG=#q=%22election-minded%22&safe=off) an [Google Books](https://www.google.ca/search?safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22election-minded%22&btnG=#safe=off&tbm=bks&q=%22election-minded%22). It is used in the news also.

Moreover, it can have several election-related meanings like someone (a voter) who is inclined to vote in an election, someone (a politician) who wants an election, someone who is "in the mood of elections" etc.

Example usages:

> Welcome to Electowiki! This is a wiki associated with the Election-methods mailing list, and communities of **election-minded** people.
>
> <sub>http://wiki.electorama.com/wiki/Main_Page</sub>
>
> ---
>
> 'Listen. We need more outdoor meetings. The kind to draw crowds. To get the populace **election-minded**. Or they'll forget to vote next month.'
>
> [Sons And Daughters *By Mary Jane Staples* (2011)]
>
> ---
>
> Election-Minded Dems Say 'No Thanks' to Obama
>
> <sub>http://www.cbn.com/cbnnews/politics/2014/October/Election-Minded-Dems-Say-No-Thanks-to-Obama/</sub>

There is also ***voting-minded*** but the usage is not prevalent.

Answer (score 0):

Use an adjective in front of *citizen* and you'll express clearly your intention. I would suggest either **exemplary** or **dutiful**

> Today I voted, I'm such a dutiful / an exemplary citizen.

- [Exemplary citizen](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22exemplary%20citizen%22&tbm=bks) yields 11,300 results on Google Books

> (a) What are the civic virtues that one should exhibit to be considered an exemplary citizen?
>   (b) An exemplary citizen should be ready to offer himself for Voting.

- [Dutiful citizen](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22dutiful%20citizen%22) produces 4,230 results

> (c) For the “dutiful citizen,” involvement in political and civic life is seen as an obligation and is expressed through conventional activities such as voting and following political news...
>
> (d) ("I am a dutiful citizen since I vote")